# How best to handle an unexpected socket error?

Tags: c#, sockets, system.reactive

I have a chat client class

```
class ChatClient
{
    Task ConnectAsync(string server);
    Task SendMessageAsync(string message);
    Task DisconnectAsync();
}
```

Once the user has connected with ConnectAsync they are able to call SendMessageAsync to send messages to other users.

Under the hood there is a Connection class which is a very basic wrapper for the Socket class. One of the main differences is that it has an OnError event.

I'm also using an observable message stream (reactive extensions) which reads from the connection and produces a stream of incoming commands from the server.

My question is this - when the socket produces an error, from where am I best to handle this error from? Should I handle it inside the OnError event handler, or should I intercept the error from the observable stream and handle it there?

I can't see any upside or downside either way, so I'm wondering what best practice dictates?

Something about having an event on a connection class has always struck me as being a little hacky, but I don't know why.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: my 2-pennies on this: *when the socket produces an error, from where am I best to handle this error from? Should I handle it inside the OnError event handler, or should I intercept the error from the observable stream and handle it there*.  I think the answer depends on the application.  I personally like to propagate it all the way back (even to the UI).  This is because this way the front end has a little more information about the error to tell the user instead of just network error.

Comment: and my second penny: *Something about having an event on a connection class has always struck me as being a little hacky*.  I don't think it's hacky at all.  In fact, in some implementations, I've seen the connection class send events back that contain the messages.  This may make sense right?  because data arrives asynchronously.  For example, when you do ConnectAsync, how do you know if the connection has actually been made?  you probably have to ask, right?  but asking requires polling.  that seems more hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that the best solution is which ever is most transparent to the end user. If the error affects the user in some way they should be notified or be given the choice of how to proceed. If it is not possible to notify the user then handle the error in a way that allows for easy future improvements.